# Multiple paginations and incremented values on a single page (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination, increment

I'm trying to increment values on button clicks. This is easy if there is only 1 button but I'm confused on how to keep track of the counts if there are **multiple** buttons. This seems even more challenging because I won't know prior to page load how many button counts I have to keep track of. The ultimate goal is to build multiple AJAX pagination schemes on a single page (load older list items from my database sequentially and specific to the item that was click).

here's the JSFiddle (below is its JS and HTML) i've started to get at this: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/menAX/6/

JS:

```
var cnt=function(id){ //this code is incomplete but hopefully you'll get the idea of what i'm trying to do...
var j=0;
for(var i=0; i>100; i++){
    if(id[i]==i) j+=5;
}
    return j;
};

$('button').click(function(){  
   var id=this.id;
   var c=cnt(id); //something which will return the current increment value of the button that was clicked 
   $('#'+id+'div').append(c+'message'+id+'<br>');
});​
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="btn1">1</button><div id="btn1div"></div>
<button type="button" id="btn2">2</button><div id="btn2div"></div>
<button type="button" id="btn3">3</button><div id="btn3div"></div>
```

The problem with this code is that clicking each of the buttons outputs the same message. Ideally, the code would be able to keep track of each button that was clicked. The way I was thinking this could work would be to tie each button's `id` with its own counter (would probably need multiple `j` counters?).

thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you need multiple j counters, why not just make j an array?

Comment: I want to keep it generic so I don't know how big the array would be ahead of page load.

Comment: You could just use an object literal; it works like a hash table.  http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

Comment: thanks i'd be interested in that. Would you mind adding an answer showing how you think it'd look?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `cnt()` function? It's checking if the character at index `i` of the `id` string is equal to `i` (except that the condition on the for loop is never true)? Why do that?

Comment: @nnnnnn i was just trying to figure out something that would keep track of each button's counts. `cnt()` was incompletely written, sorry I should have made that clear. It doesn't have to be a function.  Do you know an easier way?

Comment: Wouldn't mind an upvote for the code I produced ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a counter against each button using jQuery's [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$('button').click(function(){

    var $this = $(this),
        c = $this.data('count'); // get count for current button
    if (!c) c = 0;               // if not defined yet set to 0
    c++;                         // increment count
    $this.data('count',c);       // save updated count

    // Do something with c here
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/menAX/8/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $elem = $('#'+ this.id +'div');
    var c = $elem.children().length;
    $elem.append(c + 'message' + id + '<br>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZHW3/

Comment: thanks! that's pretty cool. Hmm, i cant decide if that will ultimately suit my needs. I'm looking for pagination so would need to add the next 10 items each time button1 is clicked, but perhaps the next 5 items for button 2 and 3.

Comment: yeah that's good too, i'm just trying to think of how I'll terminate the `append()` when my database stops returning rows...

Comment: @timpeterson - regarding how many rows to return and terminating the appending, another option is to just make an Ajax request that says "give me page x" (where x is the counter for that button) and have the backend decide how many rows would be on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Repeated here for folks who might happen to have the same question, here's how I solved the problem.  It relies on using an anonymous object, which in Javascript works like a dictionary/map/hash table.  The first time a button is pressed, the property doesn't exist, so it is initialized to one, and thereafter, it is incremented.

[This works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/acjohnson55/gYWd8/):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = {};
$(function() {

    $('button').click(function(){  
        var id=this.id;
        if (counter.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            counter[id] += 1;
        } else {
            counter[id] = 1;
        }
        var c= counter[id];
        $('#'+id+'div').append(c+' message '+id+'<br>');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="btn1">1</button><div id="btn1div"></div>
<button type="button" id="btn2">2</button><div id="btn2div"></div>
<button type="button" id="btn3">3</button><div id="btn3div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```